# Can I dedicate a task to the second core of an ESP32 with nanoFramework?

Tags: multithreading, multicore, nanoframework

I've been looking at examples on how to assign a task/function to one of the specific cores available on the ESP32.

The examples I found are mainly in C++ for Arduino.

It uses the function `xTaskCreatedPinnedToCore(,,,0)` or `xTaskCreatedPinnedToCore(,,,1)` to pin a task to a specific core.

Is there an equivalent in the nanoFramework or is this something that is automatically handled by the Thread class?

I've read this [blog](https://www.hackster.io/josesimoes/multithreading-in-net-nanoframework-f09f98) around multi threading, and it doesn't mention anything about jumping cores, instead it mentions running it in a [round and robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling) way.

I tested it out with a small app and it works great, however as it doesn't truly run in a concurrent way I was wondering if I could dedicate a process to the 1st(0th) or 2nd(1st) core?

Test Code:

```
 public static void Main()
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                PrimCalcBadly badCalc = new PrimCalcBadly();
                badCalc.DoCalc("first thread");
            }).Start();

           //new Thread(() =>
           //{
           //    PrimCalcBadly badCalc = new PrimCalcBadly();
           //    badCalc.DoCalc("second thread");
           //}).Start();

            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        class PrimCalcBadly
            {
            public void DoCalc(string calName) {
                Debug.WriteLine($"start {calName}");
                while (true)
                {
                    var sDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    for (int a = 2; a <= 1000; a++)
                    {
                        for (int b = 2; b <= 1000; b++)
                        {
                            if (a != b && a % b == 0)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    var eDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    var ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(eDate.Ticks - sDate.Ticks);
                    Debug.WriteLine($"calculation for {calName} --> {ts.TotalSeconds}");
                }
            }
        }
```

If I only run 1 instance of the calculation it takes around 2 seconds to complete execution and start again.

Output from debug window:

```
start first thread
calculation for first thread --> 2.020124999
calculation for first thread --> 2.020197
```

If I run 2 instances of the calculations it takes 4 seconds.
Output from debug window:

```
start first thread
start second thread
calculation for first thread --> 4.74040799
calculation for second thread --> 4.04035
calculation for first thread --> 4.040268
calculation for second thread --> 4.040204999
```

If I run 3 it takes 6 seconds etc...

```
start first thread
start second thread
start third thread
calculation for first thread --> 7.26084799
calculation for second thread --> 6.66085599
calculation for third thread --> 6.020959999
calculation for first thread --> 6.06095
calculation for second thread --> 6.060862999
calculation for third thread --> 6.060842
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like on full .NET, you there is no way to control which core runs a particular thread.
If you're concerned that this is not taking advantage of 2 core devices, don't worry.
On ESP32 devices that have them, the work is split between cores, like running the CLR and execution engine on one, Wi-Fi and network stuff on another, driver specific tasks, secondary tasks that execute long running operations and such.